# How to print a 'particular' element in a list (not entire list), without brackets and quotes, while printing from class method?

Tags: python, list, class-method

I am trying to print a "particular" element from a list using below code.
While printing the class instance variable `self.Engine`, the output `['Merlin']` prints along with the quotes and brackets. How can I print simply the string, without quotes and brackets?

Here is the code:

```
class Rockets(object):

    Stages = "2 Stage"

    def __init__ (self,Rocket_name,Company_Name, CEO, Headquarters, Established):
        self.Rocket_name = Rocket_name
        self.Company_Name = Company_Name
        self.CEO = CEO
        self.Headquarters = Headquarters
        self.Established = Established
        self.Engine=[]
    
    def add_engine(self,Engine_name):
        self.Engine.append(Engine_name)
            
   def Rocket_Details(self):
        return(print("Rocket:",self.Rocket_name,"\nEngine:",self.Engine,"\nStages:",self.Stages,"\nCompany Name:",self.Company_Name,"\nCEO:",self.CEO,"\nHeadquarters:",self.Headquarters,"\nEstablished:",self.Established))

Falcon9 = Rockets("Flacon9","Space Exploration Technologies Corp.","Elon Musk","Hawthorne, California",2002)
Falcon9.add_engine('Merlin')
Falcon9.Rocket_Details()
```

Output:

```
Rocket: Flacon9 
Engine: ['Merlin'] 
Stages: 2 Stage 
Company Name: Space Exploration Technologies Corp. 
CEO: Elon Musk 
Headquarters: Hawthorne, California 
Established: 2002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.join`. For example:

```py
class Rockets(object):

    Stages = "2 Stage"

    def __init__(
        self, Rocket_name, Company_Name, CEO, Headquarters, Established
    ):
        self.Rocket_name = Rocket_name
        self.Company_Name = Company_Name
        self.CEO = CEO
        self.Headquarters = Headquarters
        self.Established = Established
        self.Engine = []

    def add_engine(self, Engine_name):
        self.Engine.append(Engine_name)

    def Rocket_Details(self):
        return print(
            "Rocket:",
            self.Rocket_name,
            "\nEngine:",
            " ".join(self.Engine),  # <--- you can use str.join
            "\nStages:",
            self.Stages,
            "\nCompany Name:",
            self.Company_Name,
            "\nCEO:",
            self.CEO,
            "\nHeadquarters:",
            self.Headquarters,
            "\nEstablished:",
            self.Established,
        )


Falcon9 = Rockets(
    "Flacon9",
    "Space Exploration Technologies Corp.",
    "Elon Musk",
    "Hawthorne, California",
    2002,
)
Falcon9.add_engine("Merlin")
Falcon9.Rocket_Details()
```

Prints:

```
Rocket: Flacon9 
Engine: Merlin 
Stages: 2 Stage 
Company Name: Space Exploration Technologies Corp. 
CEO: Elon Musk 
Headquarters: Hawthorne, California 
Established: 2002
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rockets(object):

Stages = "2 Stage"

def __init__ (self,Rocket_name,Company_Name, CEO, Headquarters, Established):
    self.Rocket_name = Rocket_name
    self.Company_Name = Company_Name
    self.CEO = CEO
    self.Headquarters = Headquarters
    self.Established = Established
    self.Engine=['Unknown'] # you can replace this with empty string ['']

def add_engine(self,Engine_name):
    self.Engine.append(Engine_name)
        
def Rocket_Details(self):
     return(print("Rocket:",self.Rocket_name,"\nEngine:",self.Engine[-1],"\nStages:",self.Stages,"\nCompany Name:",self.Company_Name,"\nCEO:",self.CEO,"\nHeadquarters:",self.Headquarters,"\nEstablished:",self.Established))
```

I am guessing that the reason you have the Engine as a list is because you are expecting that the engine will change over time. If that is the logic, than the above code will output the most recent assignment of the engine name. You could add one more attribute, like self.All_Engines which would output the whole lists of the engines that were used on the rocket.